# WordPress wp_title() is blank inside echo statement

Tags: php, wordpress, header, yoast

I want to rewrite the title of my WordPress site based on the length of title. Here is the code of my `header.php` file:

```
<?php if(strlen(wp_title("", true,"")) > 60) {
  echo '<title>'.wp_title("", true,"").'</title>';
} else {
  echo '<title>'.wp_title("", true,"").' • SiteName</title>';
} ?>
```

The problem is that the returned output looks like this:

```
Actual Title Repeated Twice<title> • SiteName</title>
```

So basically, the actual title is output twice outside the `title` tags and the part inside the title tag only says `SiteName`.

I do have Yoast SEO plugin installed but "Force Rewrite Titles" is disabled.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot ?

Comment: @vieroli Screenshot of the webpage or the HTML source code of the rendered webpage?

Comment: Oh the rendered webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the 2nd argument `true` which actually echo the title,

1. if you want to use `echo` then put `false` in 2nd argument.
2. if you don't want to use `echo` then put `true` in 2nd argument.

I hope it answers